# convert utf codes to letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I'm using Ruby

I have such value in the database

> 25.02.2020 13:57:56:\nu:633;644;627;645; u:627;633;62a;627;62f; u:645;6cc;634;647; u:644;637;641; u:6a9;646;6cc;62f; u:622;645;648;632;634; u:6a9;627;631; u:628;627; u:627;6cc;646; u:628;631;646;627;645;647; u:627;632; u:635;641;631; u:62a;627; u:635;62f; u:631;648; u:628;641;631;645;627;6cc;6cc;62f; u:645;645;646;648;646; u:627;632; u:634;645;627;\n\n\nСервис

is it possible to convert it to normal persian letters with a ruby?
it must be like this

> 13:57:56:
>   سلام استاد میشه لطف کنید آموزش کار با این برنامه از صفر تا صد رو بفرمایید ممنون از شما
>   Сервис

I will be appreciative for your help

Comment: _"I have such value in the database"_ – may I ask why? It might be easier to not store the data that way in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unicode values in your string have a specific pattern:

`u:___;___;___;` where each `___` is a hexadecimal value representing a codepoint.

You can match that pattern using a regexp, and replace the encoded values with their respective Unicode chars via `gsub`:

```
str = '25.02.2020 13:57:56:\nu:633;644;627;645; u:627;633;62a;627;62f; u:645;6cc;634;647; u:644;637;641; u:6a9;646;6cc;62f; u:622;645;648;632;634; u:6a9;627;631; u:628;627; u:627;6cc;646; u:628;631;646;627;645;647; u:627;632; u:635;641;631; u:62a;627; u:635;62f; u:631;648; u:628;641;631;645;627;6cc;6cc;62f; u:645;645;646;648;646; u:627;632; u:634;645;627;\n\n\nСервис'

str.gsub(/u:((?:\h+;)+)/) { Regexp.last_match(1).split(';').map(&:hex).pack('U*') }
#=> "25.02.2020 13:57:56:\\nسلام استاد میشه لطف کنید آموزش کار با این برنامه از صفر تا صد رو بفرمایید ممنون از شما\\n\\n\\nСервис"
```

Step by step: (for each match)

- the regexp matches `"u:633;644;627;645;"`
- `Regexp.last_match(1)` returns the 1st capture group `"633;644;627;645;"`
- `split(';')` turns that into `["633", "644", "627", "645"]`
- `map(&:hex)` converts the elements to `[1587, 1604, 1575, 1605]`
- `pack('U*')` interprets them as Unicode codepoints and returns `"سلام"`